# Cannot connect to RDP on Windows 2019 member server

Tags: remote-desktop, connection

I just finished standing up a new member-server VM with Windows Server 2019 Standard, but I cannot connect to it on port 3389:

[image]

Windows Defender Firewall is disabled on all profiles:

[image]

The services are running:

[image]

The listening port is correct:

[image]

...and connections are enabled.

[image]

[image]

I've engaged the relevant troubleshooting steps from these recommendations:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/rdp-error-general-troubleshooting
- https://4sysops.com/archives/remote-desktop-cant-connect-to-the-remote-computer-reasons-and-solutions/
- https://appuals.com/fix-remote-desktop-cant-connect-to-the-remote-computer-for-one-of-these-reasons/
- https://bobcares.com/blog/remote-desktop-cant-connect-to-the-remote-computer/
- https://techgenix.com/remote-desktop-cant-connect-to-the-remote-computer/
- [Cannot RDP into Windows Server 2016: 0x80090302](https://serverfault.com/q/866450)
- [Cannot connect to virtual machine with RDP](https://serverfault.com/q/1035703)

Yet the problem persists. It's only this one. All other computers on the domain are open and listening for connections.

Is there anything more I can try?

Comment: Run netstat and see if the server is actually listening on port 3389.

Comment: Well that was a big DUH. I hadn't set the static IP yet 